# User Control Event against Form Control Event

Tags: vb.net, events, user-controls

Here is my situation, I have a user control that have the Leave event:

```
Private Sub MyControl_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Leave
    If Me.Enabled Then
        MsgBox(Property1)
    End If
End Sub
```

I have this to prevent **Leave** Event from triggering when the control is Disabled.

Then on my form, the control also has its own Leave event because I need to set some **Properties** that the **Leave** Event on the User Control needs.

```
Private Sub myControlOnForm_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyControlOnForm.Leave
    MyControlOnForm.Property1 = "value1"
End Sub
```

What happens is the first event that triggers is the one on the User Control and then the one on the form.

Now my problem is, as the code states above, I need the Form Event to trigger first before the User Control Event.

Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

The form needs to call a procedure in the user control after it's finished handling the event. Just remove the Handles Me.leave statement, and the private statement. use the sub from your form to call the controls sub which was intended to handle the event.

Note that I've changed sender As  object to sender As Mycontrol.

```
Sub MyControl_Leave(sender As Mycontrol, e As EventArgs) 
    If Me.Enabled Then
        MsgBox(Property1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Code on form

```
Private Sub myControlOnForm_Leave(sender As Mycontrol, e As EventArgs) Handles MyControlOnForm.Leave
    MyControlOnForm.Property1 = "value1"
    sender.MyControl_Leave(sender, e)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> What happens is the first event that triggers is the one on the User Control and then the one on the form.
>
> Now my problem is, as the code states above, I need the Form Event to
>   trigger first before the User Control Event.

First off, you are using the incorrect term in that problem statement.  It is not an event triggering order issue, but rather an issue in order in which the event handlers registered for the UserControl's Leave event execute.

.Net events are a form of syntactic sugar for the invocation of a multicast delegate.  When an event is raised a delegate is invoked and the order in which the handlers are executed is the order in which they were added to the delegate.  You can gain an understanding of this by working through the various "Walkthrough" tutorials located under [Events (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172877.aspx).

The *Leave* event is *Raised* by calling the *Overridable* `OnLeave` method inherited from the Control Class that is in the inheritance tree of the UserControl Class.  It is considered bad form for a class to handle its own generated event;  the preferred method is *Override* the method that raise the event.

In your case, you want the form that subscribes to the event to be notified first so that it can modify a property on the UserControl before some it performs some action in response to Leaving the UserControl.

```
Public Class UserControl1
    Protected Overrides Sub OnLeave(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLeave(e)   ' this calls the base method that Raises the event
                            ' all event handlers will run before the subsequent code
                            ' executes
        If Me.Enabled Then
            'do something
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This almost solved my problem. But now what happens is that because it calls `MyBase.OnLeave(e)`, It is Raised twice? I added `MsgBox("")` inside `If Me.Enabled Then` and it appears twice.

Comment: @NehrossMontoya, did you remove the `Private Sub MyControl_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Leave` code?  The event will only be raised once, but you can subscribe to the event multiple times.  Set a breakpoint on `MyBase.OnLeave(e)` and then step through the code to observe the execution path.